# Ambiguity on definition of addition and composition of two functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Why the definition of addition of two function is on a group $G$ of function under addition for $f,g \in G$,        $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$, but $(f+g)(x)$ is the evaluation of $f+g$ on $x$, the addition must be $f+g$ for $f,g \in G$ not their evaluation.

Also when we want to prove associative for $(f\circ g)\circ h$ we prove it for $\left((f\circ g)\circ h\right)(x)$.

Comment: Two functions from where to where?

Comment: From R to R for example or from E to F

Comment: Yes, the red addition in $(f \color{red}+ g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ is the addition being defined between functions on $G$. The $+$ on the right hand side is whatever $+$ occurs between elements of the common codomain of these functions (maybe $G$ or $\Bbb{R}$ or some other group structure?). Also, yes, to prove $(f \circ g) \circ h = f \circ (g \circ h)$, you'll need to show the functions evaluate to the same thing at every point $x$ in the domain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have functions from a set $X$ to an additive group $A$ (for example, from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, or from anything to $\mathbb{R}$, etc). Let's denote the operation on $A$ by $+$.

We want to define an "addition"/operation on the set of all such functions; let's call this operation on functions $\oplus$.

So suppose that $f$ and $g$ are functions from $X$ to $A$. I want to define a new function which I will call "$f\oplus g$" ($f$ plus $g$).

What do I need to tell you in order to define a function? I need to tell three things:

1. The domain of the function.
2. The codomain of the function.
3. The value of the function at each point in the domain.

So, what is this function "$f\oplus g$"? It is the function:

1. With domain $X$;
2. and codomain $A$;
3. Now I need to tell you the value of $f\oplus g$ at each point of the domain. The definition is:

> To calculate out the value of $f\oplus g$ at the point $x\in X$, first find the value of $f$ at $x$, then find the value of $g$ at $x$, and then *add the results* using the operation on $A$. That is:
> $$(f\oplus g)(x) = f(x)+g(x).$$

This defines the function $f\oplus g$. I **need** to tell you how to evaluate this function! This definition *completes* the determination of the function we are calling $f\oplus g$. Because I need to tell you how to evaluate the function in order to tell you what the function is.

There *is* a bit of abuse of notation, in that we often use the symbol $+$ for *both* the addition of functions and the addition of values, and then in the equation
$$(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$$
we are using $+$ for two **different** operations: the one on the left hand side is the "addition of functions", the one on the right hand side is the "addition of values". That's why I used $\oplus$ above: to make it clear these are two different operations, even if we often use the same symbol to denote them. But it is not "ambiguous" because there is only one possible interpretation for those symbols.

Similarly: when are two functions the same function? When they:

1. Have the same domain;
2. Have the same codomain; and
3. Take the same value at each and every point in the domain.

If we have function $f\colon X\to Y$, $g\colon Y\to Z$, we define $g\circ f$ to be the function with domain $X$ (domain of the first function applied), codomain $Z$ (codomain of the second function applied), and values $(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$ for every $x\in X$ (going back to the three things you need to know in order to know what a function is).

To prove associativity of composition, given an additional function $h\colon Z\to W$, we need to check that the functions $h\circ (g\circ f)$ and $(h\circ g)\circ f$ are the same function. So we need to check that they have (i) the same domain; (ii) the same codomain; and (iii) the same value at every point in the domain.

The domain of $h\circ (g\circ f)$ is the domain of $(g\circ f)$, which is the domain of $f$, namely $X$, by definition of composition. The domain of $(h\circ g)\circ f$ is the domain of $f$, namely $X$. So, same domain. *Check.*

The codomain of $h\circ (g\circ f)$ is the codomain of $h$, namely $W$. The codomain of $(h\circ g)\circ f$ is the codomain of $h\circ g$, which is the codomain of $h$, namely $W$. So, same codomain. *Check.*

Now we need to check they take  the same value at every point in the domain. How do we do that? By plugging in $x\in X$ and seeing if we get the same value. Indeed, the definitions say:
$$\begin{align*}
\bigl( h\circ (g\circ f)\bigr)(x) &= h\bigl( (g\circ f)(x)\bigr) = h\bigl( g(f(x))\bigr),\\
\bigl( (h\circ g)\circ f\bigr)(x) &= \bigl(h\circ g\bigr)(f(x)) = h\bigl(g(f(x))\bigr).
\end{align*}$$
So they take the same value at an arbitrary $x\in X$. That is, they take the same values and each and every point of the domain. *Check.*

Thus, $h\circ (g\circ f)$ and $(h\circ g)\circ f$ are *the same function*.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer

Comment: @AnasEcharkaoui If you find answers helpful, upvote them. If an answer solves your question, accept it. You have been on the site for a year and a half, asked five questions, received answers, but have yet to cast a single vote for *anything*.